# While I switched my MVC Web Application from ISS Express to Local ISS error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dll, .net-assembly

While I switched my MVC Web Application from **ISS Express to Local ISS** and tried to open my application It shoes Error Missing Dll **"Microsoft.Web.Preview"**

I searched in my local and On online for the same dll.I could not find any. Please help with how to overcome this issue.

I have also tried Nuget Package but the dll is missing there also

[image]

Comment: It may be something to do with your IIS configuration.  Check [this](https://www.mojoportal.com/Forums/Thread.aspx?pageid=5&t=2040~-1) out. By the way, that was just the first result in a web search I made after reading your question. If that doesn't address your specific issue, I'd wager that one of the other results would.

Comment: I found it on The temp dll folder in c drive